# Cannot edit specific Web Dynpro Java views in project

Tags: java, view, netweaver, webdynpro

I can't seem to edit some Web Dynpro Java views, whenever I try to edit the code it prompts me to logon to DTR and when I do logon, a DTR console appears at the bottom and still I can't edit. I repeat this step over and over again no luck.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

**Below are images of my screen results:**

[image: Logon to DTR screen]

[image: DTR console appearing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like some of your views have been checked-in already and some have not. The latter require DTR login and this is normal.
 The problem lies in that you cannot login somehow (because of permissions or other reason) and that's why you cannot edit. Try to:

1. Set up DTR client properly
2. Set up development configuration
3. Synchronize resources again

Afterwards try to edit once more.